# Custom Django Adminsite Doesn't show link to read_only ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the default Django Admin Site, if a model is registered with ForegingKey fields and those are included in readonly_fields (using the model property or the get_readonly_fields method) the value of the field is rendered with a link to the Change View, but this **Doesn't work on a custom Django Admin Site**.
E.g.: I have this two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I registered in the default Django Admin Site:

```
admin.register(ModelA)

@register(ModelB)
class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ModelB
    readonly_fields = ["model_a"]
```

So I get in the Change View of ModelB in the Admin the value of the field (**str** of the model) with a link to the Change View of the related model:

[Link pointing to Chang View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3oUW.png)

But if I register the models in a Custom Admin Site, the link is not generated.

How can I extends my Custom Admin Site in order to generate those links?

PD1: I know I can code custom methods to build the links, but this is not a DRY way of do it and doesn't work well with get_readonly_fields method

PD2: If I register the related model (ModelA in the example) in the default Admin Site the link is genereted, but point to the default Admin Site, brokening the purpose of the Custom Admin Site.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question in the official Django forum:
[forum.djangoproject.com/t/9472/5](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/custom-django-adminsite-doesnt-show-link-to-read-only-foreignkey-field/9472/9)

It has generated a ticket because is a missing line in the method get_admin_url in the helper class AdminReadOnlyField, The temporal solution is in the ticket: [code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33077](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33077)

PD: Why someone marks this post like a bad question? It has generates a ticket for a patch so it was a fair problem, this is my first question in StackOverflow and this is discouraging.

Comment: Hi Rigo, following is only to help, firstly there are a few spelling and grammar errors that make your question a bit difficult to read, its really easy to use the SO text editor to catch the spelling errors and if you have access go google-drive it helps with grammar. Then there is the link you have  to the image, it would have been better to just paste the text seen i the link into your question, I have no idea why it was downvoted but these issues if addressed would have only helped to avoid down votes. Well constructed, legible and well formatted questions always get more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nigel. According to two text editors I have only one spelling error. I posted the same question in Django Forum and was perfectly understanded. So I think the problem is that there are people who "review" the question and doesn't understand the problem, so they think the question is unclear.